# Avoiding connection strings to be apparent in a Dataflow Job Template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In a Dataflow job, I'm passing a connection string to the database that I use as a Source (JdbcIO) by leveraging environment variables. Then I use the DefaultValueFactory class to pass this value to the Pipeline options. The problem is that the connection string is still available in the Job's template file. The same thing applies when I use the connection string as an argument to the pipeline. I'm wondering if there is a more secure option when passing values to Dataflow templates.